# Sort a mongo collection by a dynamic field

Tags: mongodb

This is my collection:

```
[{"currency": "USD", "amount": 1}, 
{"currency": "EUR", "amount": 1}]
```

I would like to create a new field and **sort** my collection dynamically, using the conversion rate.

For example: 1 eur = 1.2 USD. This will return as sorted (ascending) collection:

```
[{"currency": "USD", "amount": 1, "amount_in_USD": 1}, 
{"currency": "EUR", "amount": 1, "amount_in_USD": 1.2}]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([
  {
      $addFields: {
        amount_in_USD: {
            $cond: [ {"$eq": ["$currency","EUR" ]},  { $multiply: [ "$amount", 1.2 ] },  "$amount" ]
        }
      }
  },
  {
      $sort: { amount_in_USD: -1 },
  }
])
```

Comment: i believe `$average_sales` should be changed to `$amount`